# xml schema validation using shell script

Tags: java, shell, scripting

Is it possible to  validate an XML file against a XML schema definition using shell script? Its easy to do with Java but can't find in the internet on how to get this done using shell script.

Comment: What is the difference between a 'shell script' and invoking a Java API from the command line?

Comment: More info would be helpful. There are bound to be solutions for Perl, Python, Ruby etc. It depends what you consider a 'shell script'. I'm certainly not aware of any facility to validate XML schemas in BASH & KSH. What shell are you using and what scripting languages are available?

Comment: Its a normal /bin/sh shell script. I have a xml file that has an attribute. It should be exactly four digits in length. some more validations like that. So, instead of plain string comparison, am looking for some tools/libraries that can do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have it installed you can use `xmllint --noout -schema [schema name] 
[file name]`

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you would need to either use a command line interface to a third party product, or write your own command to validate then call that from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you will like it or not, but you can  invoke a Java code from your shell script, and then you can use native API for validating an XML or other validations on data present in XML.